# Defining a term within a US bill that does not match definition within US Code

Tags: united-states, definition, bills

I am currently attempting to draft a bill for an amendment I am trying to have introduced. Within the Definitions section, I am defining a "US Person". Within the USC ([26 USC § 7701(a)(30)(A)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/7701)) a US Person is defined as:

- a citizen or resident of the United State;
- a domestic partnership;
- a domestic corporation;
- any estate; or
- or any trust.

For my purpose, I want to defined a "US Person" only as a citizen or resident of the United States, and exclude the rest. So my questions are:

1. Can I redefine a definition within the bill that is already defined within the USC, or do I need to create a new term and define that?
2. If I am able to redefine "US Person", should I also include an exclusion for partnerships, corporations, estates and trusts to ensure there is no conflict with USC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I redefine a definition within the bill that is already defined within the USC

Yes, you can. If you look at the law you cited defining "Person", it even says (emphasis mine):

> When used in this title, **where not otherwise distinctly expressed**

This contemplates that a particular law in that title could distinctly express another definition of that term. The more local term would be the one that controlled.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.